# How to find the maximum of this using Nmaximise?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

I have a function

```
 f[p_, q_, c_, x_] := 
     Log[c]*(2*x + 1 - p - q) + Log[1 - c]*(p + q - 2*x) + 
      q*((x/q)*Log[x/q] - (1 - x/q)*Log[1 - x/q]) + (1 - 
         q)*((1 - (p - x)/(1 - q))*
          Log[1 - (p - x)/(1 - q)] - ((p - x)/(1 - q))*
          Log[(p - x)/(1 - q)])
```

This is subject to certain conditions. $0<p<1, 0<q<1,0<c<1, 0<x<p$, I tried to maximise this f subject to these conditions.

`NMaximize[{f[p, q, c, x],  0 < p < 1 && 0 < q < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && 0 < x < p}, {p, q, c, x}]`

It gives me an error saying "0.2`" is not a valid variable". How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extremely difficult optimization problem. First, the maximum value of a continuous function on a noncompact set may not be achieved. Second, the arguments of the logarithms must be positive. Here is my best done with `NMaximize`:

```
NMaximize[{Log[c]*(2*x + 1 - p - q) + Log[1 - c]*(p + q - 2*x) + q*((x/q)*Log[x/q] - 
(1 - x/q)*Log[1 - x/q]) + (1 - q)*((1 - (p - x)/(1 - q))*Log[1 - (p - x)/(1 - q)] - 
((p - x)/(1 - q))*Log[(p - x)/(1 - q)]), 
0 <= p <= 1 && 0 <= q <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1 && 0 <= x <= p && 
 1 - (p - x)/(1 - q) > 0 && (p - x)/(1 - q) > 0 && 1 - x/q > 0}, {p, q, c, x}, 
Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 6000}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

> {-0.040235724512206291627660187339000988341300360257660957486419128212
> 42038286521895562117758792508277991, {p ->
> 0.43170814406681159730265583187083824112441622120650523314960727729
> 69897992977574812748455238551242614,
> q -> 0.4301340679090147534723708508594863670430177236954453316714468
> 492587270496156672563111251203220147869,
> c -> 0.9569090295389766009595904849664351705051956310898170047261569
> 646576489145425430011107039749579302614,
> x -> 0.4298933184280109540416959995873164308236214711970976650767745
> 555271997494320105427232650983623018400}}

I think the supremum equals 0 , considering $p=q$, $c$ being close to $1$, and $x<p$ being close to $p$.
The result of the command

```
MaxLimit[Log[c]*(2*x + 1 - p - q) + Log[1 - c]*(p + q - 2*x) + 
   q*((x/q)*Log[x/q] - (1 - x/q)*Log[1 - x/q]) + (1 - 
  q)*((1 - (p - x)/(1 - q))*
   Log[1 - (p - x)/(1 - q)] - ((p - x)/(1 - q))*
   Log[(p - x)/(1 - q)]) /. {p -> 1/2, q -> 1/2}, {c, x}->{1, 1/2},Direction -> "FromBelow"]
```

> 0

and Maple's results

> Matrix(3, 3, [[-0.5264520494*10^(-8), [c = 0.9999999943976654, p = 0.24140178813121238, q = 0.2414017880807429, x = 0.2414017880467214], 579], [-0.2285762942*10^(-7), [c = 0.9999999871956152, p = 0.9546206287899156, q = 0.954620639904515, x = 0.9546206287884551], 491], [-0.2347957064*10^(-7), [c = 0.9999999729593567, p = 0.15817527515336488, q = 0.15817527345368837, x = 0.15817527263676995], 335]])

confirm it.

Comment: I have plotted this function and I have been checking it out. This thing probably makes sense. But I need some time. Let me check it more and get back.

Comment: Even if you want to minimise, you do the same thing except with NMinimise function right?

Comment: @newgirl: Yes, of course. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @newgirl: The result of `MinLimit[Log[c]*(2*x + 1 - p - q) + Log[1 - c]*(p + q - 2*x) + 
   q*((x/q)*Log[x/q] - (1 - x/q)*Log[1 - x/q]) + (1 - 
      q)*((1 - (p - x)/(1 - q))*
       Log[1 - (p - x)/(1 - q)] - ((p - x)/(1 - q))*
       Log[(p - x)/(1 - q)]) /. {p -> 1/3, q -> 1/3}, {c, x} -> {1, 
   1/3}, Direction -> "FromBelow"]` which is `-\[Infinity]` shows that the target function is unbounded from below on the feasible set.

Comment: this is hazy. When I see the graph I made,    `Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[p, q, c, x]}, {x, 0, p}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}], {c, 0.001,
   1}, {p, 0.001, 1}, {q, 0.001, 1}]`                                                                                    I feel like two different sets of values of p and q, can give the same maximum. I want to make sure Also, I wanted to add one more condition to this, $p<=q$ , this gives me f value to be around -0.09. Can you check this? I want the maximum I am getting to be unique. (Because I want to use this for a saddle point approximation)

Comment: But thank you so much, this is helping immensely! :)

Comment: @newgirl: "this is hazy". Upgrade your math. Good luck!

Comment: Hahaha. Sure. But I don't think I was clear. The conditions that we are putting in, into the NMaximise function, need not be giving an overall maximum based on our conditions. Your results on Maple are different than the one coming from the Nmaximise function. For me its not just important to find 0 as a maximum, but its also about where its occurring. Through Nmaximize you get the maximum at -0.040, Maple's results  of the maximum are slightly different, the p and q values are different from one set to another. How to make sense of this? , the 2 softwares are picking different maximums.

Comment: @newgirl: As it is written in my answer, the supremum under consideration equals 0. For each $\epsilon>0, \,\epsilon<1$ the values of the target function greater than $-\epsilon$ are taken on the infinite subset of the feasible set.  Maple finds a much better approximation `-0.526452049410^(-8)` of the true supremum than Mathematica through `NMaximize` `-0.04`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109781/discussion-between-newgirl-and-user64494).

Answer (score 0):

In this approach I changed the constraints slightly to force "real f"

```
NMaximize[{f[p, q, c, x], 
{0 < c < 1,1 - (p - x)/(1 - q) > 0
, (p - x)/(1 - q) > 0, 0 < x < q}}
, {p, q,c, x}] 
(*{-0.721159, {p -> 0.160626, q -> 0.614775, c ->0.340624,x -> 0.0928292}}*)
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: Restart your Mathematica kernel and try again!

Comment: How are you getting those inequality constraints? If I solve them, I dont get the same inequalities as my original ones. Also I have tried to plot this function and see. It's weird. The maximums you are getting doesnt correspond to it somehow. This is the code that I have used. `Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[p, q, c, x]}, {x, 0, p}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}], {c, 0.001,
   1}, {p, 0.001, 1}, {q, 0.001, 1}]`

Comment: What do you think of user64494's approach?

Comment: @newgirl I'm uncertain, because the maximum depends very sensitivly on the setting of WorkingPrecision...  If you are looking for the constraints to get real f try `FunctionDomain[f[ p, q, c, x ], {p, q, c, x}]`